# How to use GetById function in c#

Tags: c#

I am learning c#. I am trying to create a basic list in a mock repository (Rather than jumping into pulling data from SQL straight away). I have a list that contains cars and has fields such as Id, Model, Make, description etc.

I am then trying to create a method in my Car.CS class, of which gets the car by Id. For example if i pass in the ID of the car, it will return the other details of the car.

Unfortunately when i run the console application, it just returns blank in the console? Could someone let me know where i'm going wrong please?

First of all i have an ICarRepository

```
namespace GeneralConsoleApp
{
    interface ICarRepository
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then i have my MockCarRepository of which contains the list

```
namespace GeneralConsoleApp
{
    class MockCarRepository : ICarRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Car> Cars =>
            new List<Car>
            {
                new Car {Id = 1, Name="BMW", Price=23000.00M, Description="BMW car" }
            };

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next is my Car.cs

```
namespace GeneralConsoleApp
{
    class Car
    {
        private readonly List<Car> CarList = new List<Car>();

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Car GetCarById(int Id)
        {
            return CarList.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == Id);

        }
    }
}
```

And finally my program.cs main method

```
namespace GeneralConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            Car car = new Car();


            Console.WriteLine(car.GetCarById(1));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, you should probably remove the `CarList` from `Car` altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues here regarding separation of concerns. Your Car model just needs to model the properties associated with a Car.

Likewise your CarRepository should contain just the methods needed to perform queries against your data store, like

```
GetCarById(int id)
```

or

```
IEnumerable<Car> FindByManufacturer(string manufacturer);
```

In terms of mocking your data store, you would create a class specifically for mocking, like MockCarRepository, and then at run-time you can instantiate it. The reason this is super useful, is that because you ultimately programming against the interface ICarRepository, when you are ready to use real data, all you need to do is create a new implementation of your ICarRepository, using whatever store you want, native SQL Connection, EntityFramework, CosmosDB etc. and just change where you are instantiating your type to satisfy the ICarRepository.

I would recommend you look into SOLID design principals - great resource below, which explains things far better than I could.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp

With a few small tweaks you could use something like the below.

```
namespace GeneralConsoleApp
{
interface ICarRepository
{
    Car GetCarById(int id);
}

class MockCarRepository : ICarRepository
{
    private List<Car> _mockCars;

    public MockCarRepository()
    {
        _mockCars = new List<Car>
        {
            new Car {Id = 1, Name="BMW", Price=23000.00M, Description="BMW car" }
        };
    }

    public Car GetCarById(int id)
    {
        return _mockCars.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == id);
    }
}

class SqlCarRepository : ICarRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public SqlCarRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public Car GetCarById(int id)
    {
        // use the _connectionString to create your database connection.
        var car = FROM DATABASE;
        return car;
    }
}

class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // All repositories should implement ICarRepository
        // meaning switching repo implementation is a one line change below, a DI container adjustment, or some sort of strategy pattern.
        ICarRepository mockRepo = new MockCarRepository();;

        var carFound = mockRepo.GetCarById(1);

        Console.WriteLine("Found car: " + carFound.Description);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you Phil. In the event that it wasn't mock data, and was in fact pulling from a SQL database, would the Car.cs contain the methods to retrieve the data instead of the method being in the MockRepo?

Comment: @Matty21202 you would need one more layer which takes IRepository as input. See my answer below. Phil, hope you also agree.

Comment: @DeepakMishra Thank you. Sorry, 1 more question. What is the point in me having the ICarRepository, if the car class has exactly the same properties? i may as well just implement them in the car class and get rid of the ICarRepository? At the moment i have the same properties defined in all of my class files which seems very repetitive?

Comment: `ICarRepository` will help you in mocking. It should contain various operations which you can do on Car/s. `Car` should be used as model with only data fields/properties.

Comment: Hi Matty - No need to adjust anything other than adding an implementation of your ICarRepository interface, i.e. SqlCarRepository. I have updated my sample code above. Hope it helps. Many people will use EntityFramework, so an example would be that your Concrete repository would accept your DbContext and you can then use that to connect to SQL. Happy to help.

Comment: @Phil Thank you! much appreciated.

Comment: @Phil What is the point of having ICarRepository here, when you are not using it? You should use some composition and DI here (strategy pattern) , so that you can showcase the concept of mocking.  You should have a single class where you can inject the ICarRepository, so that while writing Unit Tests you can provide mocked repository to it, while in actual you inject the SQLRepository.

Comment: @DeepakMishra Fair comment, although I really just wanted to make minimal changes to Matty's code as he was pretty much there in what he had. Obviously in production environment these types would be injected, so this is really just for demonstration purposes to help with education. I have adjusted the instantiation of the repository to make that clearer. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Car` class does not use `MockCarRepository` but has it's own empty list instead (`CarList`).

You should either populate the list in the `Car` or use the mock repository there.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that your Car class has a list of Car types from which you are returning a value to the console.

You should be returning a value from the Repository instead.

```
nammespace GeneralConsoleApp
{
    class MockCarRepository : ICarRepository
    {
           public IEnumerable<Car> Cars => new List<Car>
           {
                   new Car {Id = 1, Name="BMW", Price=23000.00M, Description="BMW car" }
           };

           public Car GetCarById(int Id)
           {
             return Cars.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == Id);
           }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var Repository = new MockRepository();


            Console.WriteLine(Repository.GetCarById(1));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CarList is an empty list and that's the reason of having no output.

Change main call to

```
MockCarRepository car = new MockCarRepository();
Console.WriteLine(car.GetCarById(1).Name);
```

and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it something like

```
ICarRepository repository= new MockCarRepository();
CarService carService= new CarService(repository);
Console.WriteLine(carService.GetCarById(1));
```

You would need to add CarService class which can inject the mock repository or actual database repository and modify Car class to be a model.

```
    class CarService
    {
        private readonly ICarRepository _repository;
        public CarService(ICarRepository repository)
        {
           _repository=repository;
        }

        public Car GetCarById(int Id)
        {
            return _repositoy.GetCarById(id);    
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }       
    }
    interface ICarRepository
    {
        Car GetCarById(int Id);
    }
    class MockCarRepository : ICarRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Car> Cars =>
            new List<Car>
            {
                new Car {Id = 1, Name="BMW", Price=23000.00M, Description="BMW car" }
            };
        public Car GetCarById(int Id)
        {
            return Cars.First(z => z.Id == Id);    
        }
    }
```